# acumatica REST API ID changes between API calls

Tags: rest, api, acumatica

In Acumatica 2019R1 Build 19.103.0030, I am getting different .id values for the same database entry on subsequent API calls.

```
entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder?$filter=OrderNbr eq 'ME064830'
```

returns

```
id : "a02bcdeb-f15b-4d12-b290-190eaeaa9978"
```

a subsequent call to the exact same endpoint returns

```
id : "447c87dc-0b19-47ee-95b1-2ee4ebcddbf3"
```

As specified in the REST API course, I logout between every API call.

If I do NOT logout between API calls, the same ID is returned.

Has the REST API protocol for logging in/out changed in 2019R1?

Also, isn't the .id supposed to be the unique identifier in the SQL database for that row? It does not seem like that should change between API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID is not a database key value. From what I can find it is suppose to be different as you have described for each logout/login:

> The session entity ID is a GUID that is assigned to each entity you
>   work with during an Acumatica ERP session. You can obtain the value of
>   the session entity ID from the ID property of an entity returned from
>   Acumatica ERP. The session entity ID is different for each new session
>   with Acumatica ERP. That is, after a new login to Acumatica ERP, you
>   cannot use the session entity ID that you received in the previous
>   session to work with the entity.

Reference: [Help.Acuamtica.com - Retrieval of a Record by ID](https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=bc9531b0-717b-4b2d-8899-ff7ca805ade1)

If you want the same sales order ever time you will need to supply the dual key of Order Type and Order Nbr.

**EDIT:** Starting in 2019R2 you should receive the same ID back between sessions. This is only true for top level entities that use NoteID.